# syncrepl syncing but not updating

Tags: openldap

## Problem description

There are two openldap servers: "provider" and "consumer". The provider works fine and is accessible by the consumer at localhost:1000 using an stunnel.

If the consumer is started with an empty database, it automatically syncs the provider's db and is working fine.

But if something is changed on the provider later, it doesn't get to the consumer.

---

## Configurations

The domains are changed, the password is redacted. There is an `ldapsync` account on the provider that is used for syncing.

### Provider

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0

OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.11 (Jul 23 2010 21:37:26)

```
$ less /etc/ldap/slapd.conf
[...]
moduleload      syncprov.la
[...]
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 10 60
syncprov-sessionlog 1000
```

### Consumer

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0

OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.11 (Jul 24 2010 08:14:20)

```
$ less /etc/ldap/slapd.conf
[...]
syncrepl rid=123
  provider=ldap://localhost:1000
  type=refreshAndPersist
  interval=00:00:05:00
  searchbase="dc=mydomain,dc=com"
  scope=sub
  schemachecking=off
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="cn=ldapsync,ou=Roles,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
  credentials=<***REDACTED***>
```

---

## What have I tried so far?

I was working mainly based on: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/syncrepl.html

I've tried `type=refreshOnly` instead of `type=refreshAndPersist`.

Comment: I had this same problem and it was because I hadn't imported a schema (samba.schema in this case). The consumer would sync until a record that had a samba attribute and stop, without any updates taking place later. Maybe yours have something related to that?

Answer (score 1):

Syncrepl uses "cookie" in search requests. If "cookie" is the same as "contextCSN:" in providers database, then 0 records returned.
After any updates in database - "contextCSN:" must be automatically changed by LDAP process . But in some reasons it may be hang, for example if clocks unsynchronized. You may create full dump of database (by "slapcat") and check field "contextCSN:"